# Woocommerce: Category image as product placeholder image

Tags: image, woocommerce

Woocommerce only allows a single placeholder image for products, but unique images for each category.

The client sells alcohol. There are 5 major categories of products: beer, cider, coolers, liquor, wine.

What I would like to do is use the category image for the product placeholder image if an actual product image does not exist. If a product is in the 'wine' category, then the product's placeholder image would be the category image for "wine".

Here is a mockup of what I would like to accomplish: [Placeholder image = category image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQUo5.jpg)